# How do I make a responsive button?

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 
}


body{
 background-image:url(background.svg);
 background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size:100%;
}


.play{
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}





.parent{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

button {
  all: unset;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 17px; 
   z-index: 3;
   position: absolute;
   top:53%;

}


#button {
  width: 20%;
  height: 18%;
  background-color: #ffbf00;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 #c49102;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;

}

#button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}



 .bg {
  position: absolute;
  width :20%;
  height: 18%;
  border-radius: 17px;
  outline: #ffbf00 solid 3px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation : pulse 1.5s infinite alternate;
  top:53%;
  
}


@keyframes pulse{
0% {
transform :scale(1,1);

}
100% {
transform : scale(1.1, 1.20);

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <title>Pulsing Button</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent">

  <button id="button" >
 Buttton
  </button> 
  
  <div class="bg"></div>
  

</div>


<script src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an SVG file which is basically a box serving as a background. Inside that box (background) is a smaller box and inside that smaller box is a button. The SVG file (the background and smaller box) was created in Illustrator. The BUTTON (inside the smaller box) was created in HTML and CSS.
Here’s my problem, whenever I minimize the browser size the BUTTON doesn’t scale properly along with the SVG file. It doesn’t maintain its positioning inside the smaller box (padding, ratio, size).
Here is a link to the project with the SVG background https://ilikeacode.github.io/button/

Comment: You'll still need to sort out the pulsing bit, but you can get a long way with `#button {width: 18vw; height: 6vw; font-size: 3vw; transform: translateY(calc(2vw - 24px));}` - a `vw` is a unit representing 1% of the viewport width. You can also use `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` (and more). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units